# append data before record with dynamic change

Tags: javascript

I 've file having records like given below

```
21001123
22000000
23000000
25000000
50010000      For example ...here AFTER SEQUENCE ID(50), NEXT TWO CHARACTERS(01) SHOWS HOW MANY HOUSE IN THIS TOWER (001)
21002123
22000000
23000000
25000000
21002456
22000000
23000000
50020000
21003123
22000000
23000000
25000000
21003456
22000000
23000000
25000000
21003456
22000000
23000000
25000000
50030000
```

Explanation of data..

First look at the records starting from 21. First two characters of every record is sequence id.
Then in records starting from 21, after sequence id, its a field called society code and its length is 6. Out of 6, first three characters are tower number and rest three characters are house number in same tower.

So as you can see whenever the tower number changes, record starting from 50 comes and tell how many houses are there in that tower.
Record number starting from 22, 23 and 25 give information about specific house under any tower. One more fact here is that, 50the record comes up which tells number of houses in a tower, whenever tower number gets changed. So 21, 22. 23 and 25, its an info of one house...it would be kind of group of records loop

I want to add two identifiers before all records staring from 21.

When ever a tower changes identifier should be incremented by one, and when a house exceeds in same tower identifier should be increased by one, but in this case tower would be same so null should be there.

Here is an expected result.

```
1121001123
22000000
23000000
25000000
50010000 
2121002123
22000000
23000000
25000000
n221002456
22000000
23000000
50020000
3121003123
22000000
23000000
25000000
n221003456
22000000
23000000
25000000
n321003456
22000000
23000000
25000000
50030000
```

I'm reading file containing all these records one by one. And it contains more records as well which we dont know how many while reading one by one. How can I achieve this ?

Please share your ideas , then I will use that idea as a reference to proceed further.

Thanks..!!